# A question in Hartshorne's Proposition 2.3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On the top of p.74, he said: Since $f^{\#}$ is a local homomorphism, it follows that ${\varphi}^{-1}(p)=f(p)$. But I can't see why. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't you think including more details would make it easier for someone to help?

Comment: We don't have the book on hand. You'll need to include all the relevant information.

Comment: I have added the text.@AlexisOlson @ Mike Pierce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following diagram commutes

$$\begin{matrix} A & \xrightarrow{\phi} & B \\ \downarrow i & & \downarrow j\\ A_{f(\mathfrak p)} & \xrightarrow{f_{\mathfrak p}^{\sharp}} & B_{\mathfrak p} \end{matrix}$$

Now $P = f(\mathfrak p)$ is some prime ideal of $A$.  Since $f^{\sharp}_{\mathfrak p}: A_{f(\mathfrak p)} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak p}$ is a local homomorphism, the preimage of the unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak p B_{\mathfrak p}$ of $B_{\mathfrak p}$, is equal to the unique maximal ideal $PA_{P}$ of $A_P$.  So

$$P = i^{-1} PA_P = i^{-1} (f^{\sharp -1}_{\mathfrak p} \mathfrak p B_{\mathfrak p}) = \phi^{-1}( j^{-1} \mathfrak p B_{\mathfrak p}) = \phi^{-1} \mathfrak p$$